# How does an html form listen for a submit event

Tags: html, event-listener

Does the form create something similar to an event listener for all submit buttons or does each submit button trigger the form?

For context, I am making a site that has 100+ photos. They all have an event listener that calls the same function on click (with different data). I wonder if it would be more efficient to wrap each photo in a submit button, and put all buttons in a form with an event listener that triggers on submit.

I'm guessing the button approach would be more efficient because it only uses one event listener, whereas the first approach would require the photos to attend to all actions all the time. But I wanted to double check that the form won't attend to all 100+ buttons in some way that's similar to event listeners, and thus making the button approach as (in)efficient as the first approach.

Comment: You could just set the event listener on the `<body>`, or some containing element like a `<div>` and examine the event object that's passed to the listener to see which element triggered the event. This is called [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

Answer (score 0):

Each submit button triggers (sends) the form, so you'd just be creating extra work if you wrapped each photo in a submit button. You'd still need to create an event listener, as well as cancel the default submit action. Multiple submit buttons is also not recommended for accessibility (it can cause problems for keyboard users).

Adding a single event listener to a container element is best, as described in the comment by @tangentially-perpendicular.